# Find all patterns in a multifasta file, including overlapping motifs

Tags: python, perl

I have a multifasta file, it looks like this:

```
>NP_001002156.1
MKTAVDRRKLDLLYSRYKDPQDENKIGVDGIQQFCDDLMLDPASVSVLIVAWKFRAATQCEFSRQEFLDG
MTDLGCDSPEKLKSLLPRLEQELKDSGKFRDFYRFTFSFAKSPGQKCLDLEMAVAYWNLILSGRFKFLGL
WNTFLLEHHKKSIPKDTWNLLLDFGNMIADDMSNYAEEGAWPVLIDDFVEFARPIVTAENLQTL
>NP_957070.2
MAKDAGLKETNGEIKLFINQSPGKAAGVLQLLTVHPASITTVKQILPKTLTVTGAHVLPHMVVSTPQRPT
IPVLLTSPHTPTAQTQQESSPWSSGHCRRADKSGKGLRHFSMKVCEKVQKKVVTSYNEVADELVQEFSSA
DHSSISPNDAVSSCHVYDQKNIRRRVYDALNVLMAMNIISKDKKEIKWIGFPTNSAQECEDLKAERQRRQ
ERIKQKQSQLQELIVQQIAFKNLVQRNREVEQQSKRSPSANTIIQLPFIIINTSKKTIIDCSISNDKFEY
LFNFDSMFEIHDDVEVLKRLGLALGLESGRCSAEQMKIATSLVSKALQPYVTEMAQGSVNQPMDFSHVAA
ERRASSSTSSRVETPTSLMEEDEEDEEEDYEEEDD
>NP_123456.1
MALLLLLGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGG
...
```

Although there is a great python script to handle motif searches in a multifasta file (https://www.biostars.org/p/14305/), if pattern "[KHR]{3}" was used,
it would return only motif list and many empty results:

```
>NP_001002156.1
:['RRK']
>NP_001002156.1
:[]
>NP_001002156.1
:['HHK']
>NP_957070.2
:[]
>NP_957070.2
:['RRR']
...
```

and some motif (HKK) was leaked in the same sequence.

Here I found another python script:

```
#coding:utf-8
import re
pattern = "[KHR]{3}"
with open('seq.fasta') as fh:
    fh.readline() 
    seq = ""
    for line in fh:
         seq += line.strip() 
rgx = re.compile(pattern)
result = rgx.search(seq)
patternfound = result.group()
span = result.span()
leftpos = span[0]-10
if leftpos < 0:
   leftpos = 0
print(seq[leftpos:span[0]].lower() + patternfound + seq[span[1]:span[1]+10].lower())
```

it returns the first matched motif found in a context (forward 10 amino acids after the matched motif, 
and backward 10 before the matched motif) for only one fasta (the 1st one) sequence, for the first fasta 
sequence NP_001002156.1 using the scirpt, the returned result:

```
mktavdRRKldllysrykd
```

but it has no file header">NP_001002156.1" and other 2 motifs in context were all ommitted:

```
glwntfllehHHKksipkdtwnl
lwntfllehhHKKsipkdtwnll
```

Here, I want the desired script to return matched motif with its postition in a context of each fasta 
sequence in the multifasta file, and it would present the results as following:

```
>NP_001002156.1_matchnumber_1_(7~9)
mktavdrRRKldllysrykd
>NP_001002156.1_matchnumber_2_(148~150) 
glwntfllehHHKksipkdtwnl
>NP_001002156.1_matchnumber_3_(149~151)
lwntfllehhHKKsipkdtwnll
>NP_957070.2_matchnumber_1_(163~165)
chvydqknirRRRvydalnvlma
>NP_123456.1
no match found
```

Note:
The positon of matched pattern is not the position of context.

Anyone could help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: So what is "motif" ?  A three-letter pattern?  Why is it "RRK" in one example but then HHK in the other, overlapping with HKK in the next one and then RRR in the last one?  Can you please explain? (Or do you want only people who know this to respond?)

Comment: Hang on ... any three-character combination out of [HKR]?

Comment: How large can these files be?

Comment: @zdim It won't be only HKR or some other pattern it will differ, we have to look on the protein folding and protein properties. Protein sequence not like DNA sequence so the maximum size of the protein ~50K characters. But in the file we can keep n number of sequence, Fasta sequence header starts with `>`

Comment: @zdim，the Regex pattern syntax could be used to search predefined pattern among any strings, this example is just protein sequences. The file size is about 40Mb, thank you!

Comment: @mkHun and `james`: Look, I am not a biologist. I am prepared to help out here but you aren't helping.  Can you please look at my first comment and tell me what "motif" means? Is it what I guessed in my second comment?

Comment: @ zdim, thank you very much! motif is some character position conserved strings, for example: P[A-Z]{2}P, the Ps in the 1st and last positon are conserved, while in the 2nd postion, the character can be any character among A~Z, here it can be doubled, so there is the 3rd postion which is the same as 2nd because of {2} parameter, means: AA, AC, ...YZ, any 2 character combinations there are OK.

Comment: OK, that does explain what "motif" is, thank you.  So in this question it is specifically [HKR]{3}, correct?  (Meaning either of HHH, HHK, HKR, ... etc).  See my answer.

Comment: @zdim, Yes, you are right! For [KHR]{3}, it means, there are 3 postions, and the character at  3 postions are any character among K, H or R, so RRK  is correct, obviously, HHK, HHH,HKK ...if it has that of strings, are all correct.

Comment: @ zdim, in fact, you can define the motif based on your research and the rules of Regex.

Comment: Alright, good, that's what I figured.  So that is what you need in this question, specifically [KHR]{3}?  Then my answer should be fine.

Comment: @ zdim, yes, In the question, I want to combine the two scripts or other script created to output the results I wanted, Thank you !

Comment: @james  I wrote code to produce the output you explained;  I didn't use (nor care for) those two scripts. It catches all you stated, overlapping motifs included.

Comment: Note: the python code you show _cannot_ catch overlapping motifs (like HHKK) since after the first match (HHK) their regex will have passed the needed position for the second match (it is _after_ the first K so all it sees next is only one K). To get that one can use "lookahead" (or other more complex approaches), as in my answer.

Comment: @zdim, Yes, your considerations are right, if there are overlapping motifs, it is best to find them in a pool or collected form (like HHKK). Just as mkHun said, the pattern or motif in this case will differ, so I can change your code to match the motif I wanted besides of [KHR]{3} ?  Thank you very much !

Comment: @james  Yes, you can change that, at that one place where it's used.  I didn't extract it into a variable because: (1) I didn't know what "motif" was (2) After your explanation, I see that there may be fixed characters ("conserved" ones) in which case the regex may need a tweak.

Comment: @zdim, thank you for your explanation in detail $ patient.

Comment: I've edited the title to be more precise, and to mention overlapping which is an important part of the problem here.  If you don't like it please by all means "roll back" :).  You can do that by clicking on "edited ..." below the middle of the question (above my username) and then you'll see the revisions, and "roll back" option on the previous one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "motif" here is any three-long combination of [HKR] characters; motifs may overlap.

The overlapping is resolved by using a "lookahead" in the regex.   See details below. Neither of quoted or shown resources seem to handle that and I don't see how they would catch overlapping motifs.

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';

my $file = shift || die "Usage: $0 fasta-file\n";    
open my $fh, '<', $file or die "Can't open $file: $!";

my ($seq, $seq_name);
while (<$fh>) {
    chomp;
    if (/^>(.*)/) {
        # Process the previous assembled sequence
        if ($seq) {
            proc_seq($seq_name, $seq);
            $seq = ''; 
        }
        $seq_name = $1; 
        next;
    }   
    $seq .= $_; 
}
# Process the last one    
proc_seq($seq_name, $seq);

sub proc_seq {
    my ($seq_name, $seq, $multiline) = @_; 

    # Build output in the loop, as motifs are found. By default, print all
    # output for one seq_name in one line. To print each motif on its own
    # line instead, invoke this sub with a true third argument (1 will do).
    my $output = ">$seq_name";

    my $cnt = 0;
    while ($seq =~ /([HKR])(?=([HKR]{2}))/g) { 
        ++$cnt;
        my $motif = $1 . $2; 
        my $pos = pos($seq);
        my $pre_context = ($pos >= 11) 
            ? substr($seq, $pos-11, 10) 
            : substr($seq, 0,       $pos-1);
        my $post_context = substr $seq, $pos+2, 10;

        $output .= " n$cnt($pos~" . ($pos+2) . ") ";
        $output .= "\n"  if $multiline;
        $output .= lc($pre_context) . $motif . lc($post_context);
    } 
    say ($cnt > 0  ? $output  : $output . ' no match found');
}
```

Note on the regex: we need a [lookahead](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html#Looking-ahead-and-looking-behind) for the second and third character in order to be able to catch the overlapping motifs as well.

An example. There is `HHKK` in the first sequence, with overlapping motifs `HHK` and `HKK`. If the regex matches `HHK` using `/[HKR]{3}/` then after that the position of the regex engine in the string is after the first `K`, as it "consumed" `HHK`.  So all it can see next is just one `K` and so there is no `[HKR]{3}` to match next, and it thus misses the next motif.

So, instead, I match only one letter and do a "lookahead" for the next two. Then after matching `H` (and "seeing" that there is indeed `HK` following) only one letter is consumed and the engine got past only that first `H`, and it is positioned before the second `H` for the next match. Now it will be able to next match the `HKK`, in the same manner (and so it can keep matching even multiply overlapping motifs).

This identifies everything indicated in the desired output (which has a typo); note the change in the requirements in the comment, to print all motifs for one sequence on one line. So it prints

```
>NP_001002156.1 n1(7~9) mktavdRRKldllysrykd n2(148~150) lglwntflleHHKksipkdtwnl n3(149~151) glwntfllehHKKsipkdtwnll
>NP_957070.2 n1(163~165) schvydqkniRRRvydalnvlma
>NP_bogus_with_no_motifs  no match found
```

with all motifs for the same sequence name on one line, as wanted. I've added a bogus line to input, with no motifs, to test the `no match found` addition; this drew the last line in the output above.

---

There is still an option to print each motif on a separate line, as was originally wanted: invoke the `proc_seq` function with an additional, third, argument which is true, like

```
proc_seq($seq_name, $seq, 1)
```

and then it'll print

```
>NP_001002156.1 n1(7~9) 
mktavdRRKldllysrykd n2(148~150) 
lglwntflleHHKksipkdtwnl n3(149~151) 
glwntfllehHKKsipkdtwnll
>NP_957070.2 n1(163~165) 
schvydqkniRRRvydalnvlma
>NP_bogus_with_no_motifs  no match found
```

Comment: @james Added a detailed explanation of how the regex in the answer catches overlapping motifs.  (Note, there are yet other ways of course.)

Comment: @ zdim， It works very well and very fast ! I appreciate your great help ！

Comment: @james  Great :)  Let me know if questions pop up

Comment: @james Welcome :)  I just fixed numbers for an "edge case" (when there isn't enough characters in the string before the match, to print 10 for context -- it was off by 1)

Comment: Exellent ! If no matches found in sequence, for example, NP_123456.1 no matches found, would it give the result >NP_123456.1 \n no match found ? I have edited the post.

Comment: please see the last comment and edited post. Many thanks!

Comment: @james If you wish that, add a flag (`my $cnt=0;`) at the beginning of the function, and increment it inside the `while` loop, so when there are matches.  After the `while` loop, check that variable and if it is still zero then there were no matches found and you can print that.

Comment: I try it as you said, it is perfect !  Thank you very much!

Comment: when the pattern is like '/([KHR])(?=([KHR]{2,}))/g', sometime it will return the correct pattern in the sequence, but wrong postion of the border, for example, >NP_001002156.1  (150~152)
glwntflleHHKKksipkdtwnl, it is actually 150~153. How to fix this bug ? Thank you very much !

Comment: @james  That is now a variable motif length?  Then you'd have to see how much you actually got in the second capture.  The `$pos+2` is there now since in the example in the question we always have two more chars (after the first one).  If that is not fixed then take the length: `$pos+length($2)`.  (Or, since that will be used more than once store it in a variable first.)

Comment: awsome !!!,  I changed the $pos+2 into $pos+length($2), and place $cnt as matchnumber, it is perfectly running ! Your perl code is a gate for me to learn perl, Thank you very much !!!

Comment: If one sequence of multifasta file has many defined motifs, I want the output is one line for later easy handling, for example, the fasta sequence NP_001002156.1 has 3 defined motifs, I want the 3 motifs and their ranges presented in one line as following: >NP_001002156.1  (7~9) mktavRRKldllysrykd (148~150) glwntfllehHHKksipkdtwnl (149~151) lwntfllehhHKKsipkdtwnll. I have tried to edit your script to get that, but sadly I failed, Could you help me to figure it out ? Thanks!

Comment: @james  Editing ... once we are at it, a question: is it useful to have output lined up in some way -- for example, so that it's columnar? It doesn't seem to matter, since there can be many different positions/numbers of motifs, but if it does it's easy to add.

Comment: I just want it lined up in a line and separated by space, because motif is just one factor I want to filtered, it is just enough for the pairs of motif region and motif seperated by space, Thank you for your kind reply !

Comment: @james OK. Edited, please have a look.  I will now edit some more, to improve text/explanations; please let me know if something isn't right or can be improved.

Comment: it gives me the result I wanted, It is awsome  !!!  One question is when the sequence do not have a motif, I want to add "no match found", and one more stuff is to add a $cnt to count the number of the motif, for example, ">NP_001002156.1 matchnumber1(7~9) mktavdRRKldllysrykd matchnumber2(148~150) lglwntflleHHKksipkdtwnl matchnumber3(149~151) glwntfllehHKKsipkdtwnll", Could you help me ? Thank you vey much!

Comment: @james Sure ... literally `matchnumberX` ?  (It's a big phrase, I'd rather use `numX` or even `nX` :)

Comment: @james Added (and tested but of course please check)

Comment: @james For some reason I forgot to actually add it here (only tested in my code), sorry -- now it **is** added. And count report changed to `nX`

Comment: @yeah, it is great !, please add the  $cnt++ before the "my $motif = $1 . $2;" in the while loop, just as you suggested before. Now, It gives me the desired result !

Comment: wow, when I am busy testing your code, you have write a detailed techinique article for the question. Thank you very much for helping us!!!