# Finding repeating tagged substrings

Tags: regex, perl

I have a file where the lines are made up of fields that are:

- Delimited by alphanumeric tags that start with a special character ('%' in my example below)
- The tag text is terminated with a space
- The content of the field is terminated by ','
- The field content will never contain **%** or **,**

An example line:

> %a astuff,%b bstuff,%t this,%u that,%v this,%t that,%x the other,%xx only once,%q the other,%z the other,%c cstuff

Sets of tags are significant for searching -- This is the tag set for my example:

> %t, %u, %v, %w, %x, %xx, %y, %z

I want to find the content of fields where the tag is in the set and the field content is repeated in a subsequent field tagged from the set. Here is the code of my unsuccessful attempt:

```perl
my $tagmrkr='%';
my $line='%a astuff,%b bstuff,%t this,%u that,%v this,%t that,%x the other,%xx only once,%q the other,%z the other,%c cstuff';

my $searchtags = qr/t|u|v|w|x|xx|y|z/; # excludes q

print qq/The line:$line\n\n/;
for ($line =~ m/
    $tagmrkr$searchtags\ ([^\,]*,)
    .*?
    $tagmrkr$searchtags\ \1
    /gx) {
        print qq/First field contents:$1\n/;
        print qq/Entire match:$&\n/;
        print qq/\n/;
        }
```

I was expecting:

```
The line:%a astuff,%b bstuff,%t this,%u that,%v this,%t that,%x the other,%xx only once,%q the other,%z the other,%c cstuff

First field contents:this,
Entire match:%t this,%u that,%v this,

First field contents:the other,
Entire match:%x the other,%xx only once,%q the other,%z the other,
```

I got:

```
The line:%a astuff,%b bstuff,%t this,%u that,%v this,%t that,%x the other,%xx only once,%q the other,%z the other,%c cstuff

First field contents:the other,
Entire match:%x the other,%xx only once,%q the other,%z the other,

First field contents:the other,
Entire match:%x the other,%xx only once,%q the other,%z the other,
```

Question 1:
Why is the `$1` and `$&` for first match being replaced by the values from the second match?

Question 2: -- What should I change to get what I *want* (below) not what I expect?

What I want is to be able to re-pivot the match so that it also finds the repeated field in spite of overlaps -- where the first field of the second match occurs before the second field of the first match. Actually, for my immediate purposes, all I need is the duplicated field content.

I.e., I want 3 matches from the example:

```
The line:%a astuff,%b bstuff,%t this,%u that,%v this,%t that,%x the other,%xx only once,%q the other,%z the other,%c cstuff

First field contents:this
Entire match:%t this,%u that,%v this,

First field contents:that
Entire match:%u that,%v this,%t that,

First field contents:the other
Entire match:%x the other,%xx only once,%q the other,%z the other,
```

Comment: Try replace `for` with `while`

Comment: "_field content is repeated in a subsequent field tagged from the set_" -- repeated anywhere further in selected tags, not necessarily in the very next one?

Comment: @zdim yes I'm interested in any repeats, so long as it is in a field tagged by one of the tags in the set.

Comment: @HåkonHægland, This gives me what I expected (Question 1), although I don't understand why the two constructs are different.

Comment: I guess they are different because `for` evaluates the regex operator in list context and `while` evaluates it in scalar context

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to provide for overlaps is to *assert* the presence of the rest of the phrase, using [lookahead](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut#Looking-ahead-and-looking-behind). Then that part is not consumed and the engine continues from before it and so it can match it again

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';

my $s = q(%a astuff,%b bstuff,%t this,%u that,%v this,%t that,)
      . q(%x the other,%xx only once,%q the other,%z the other,%c cstuff); 

my $m = qr/%/;
my $t = qr/(?:t|u|v|w|x|xx|y|z)/; 

while ($s =~ / $m$t \s ([^,]+) , (?=(.*?$m$t\s\g{1},?)) /gx) { 
    say "capture: $1";
    say "  whole: $1,$2";
}
```

For a more detailed explanation of how the lookahead helps in catching overlapping patterns see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54141728/4653379)

Prints

```
capture: this
  whole: this,%u that,%v this,
capture: that
  whole: that,%v this,%t that,
capture: the other
  whole: the other,%xx only once,%q the other,%z the other,
```

Comment: The first matched field should include the terminating comma to avoid matching an unterminated  longer second match. I.e., q(%x the other,%xx only once,%q the other,%z the others,%y the other,%c cstuff) '%x the other,' should not match the '%z the others,' It should keep looking until it finds '%y the other,'

Comment: @Wes Alright, I left it out so to not be in a capture since it merely separates records. But that of course isn't some important criterion. Now the prints have a trailing comma, please review

Comment: upon reflection, it's good to have the first comma  out of the capture, and also out of the look-ahead. the second comma has to be included in the look ahead to avoid matching a super-string.  `while ($s =~ / $m$t \s ([^,]+) , (?=(.*?$m$t\s\g{1}) , ) /gx) {` also I would use a semicolon in the say statement to `say "capture: $1; wh...` to make it clear that the comma isn't in the capture.

Comment: @Wes OK, so I rolled it back. Before we update the printout format (good call), let's discuss these commas.  Why do you want the trailing comma included? (Is there a deeper reason related to the use of this?)  For one thing, the last field has no trailing comma; so whichever way one includes it in the pattern it has to be optional, too (otherwise the last field would never be matched!).  Doable, but then the output will differ for a case which happens to catch that last field.  Let me know what you think

Comment: @Wes I adjusted the print format, so that it's unambiguous. Let me know what you think of commas, and I'll think more.

Comment: I don't really want to capture the field terminator. I do need it to compare the two fields. If the second field has extra trailing characters it will trigger a false positive match if the terminators are not included. ... BTW the actual script uses '\' instead of '%' for the tag marker and '#' instead of ',' for the field terminator. The # is a replacement for <EOL>. In the original file, the fields are one per line. See https://github.com/WesPeacock/DaasanachScripts/blob/master/MakeCompForm.pl and the sample.sfm file at the same site

Comment: Add a comma to the end of the second field and it'll be good.

Comment: @Wes Alright, I added the comma, which must be optional. (Remove the `%c...` so that the string ends with `%z the other` and then the last match won't work unless there's that `?`.)  I still don't understand why that comma is needed but you know the problem :).  I'll go sleep on it now

Answer (score 0):

Using a global match in a `for` loop will return all matches at once (and then iterates over the matches), hence the match variables will be set to the last successful match (before starting the iteration), whereas using the global regexp match in a while condition evaluates it in scalar context such that the match variables will be correct for each iteration.

You can get all three matches by resetting `pos $line` for each iteration. E.g. using the following approach:

```
while ($line =~ m/
      $tagmrkr$searchtags\ ([^\,]*,)
      .*?
      $tagmrkr$searchtags\ \1
   /gx) {
    pos $line = $-[0] + 1;
    print qq/First field contents:$1\n/;
    print qq/Entire match:$&\n/;
    print qq/\n/;
}
```

**Output**:

```
The line:%a astuff,%b bstuff,%t this,%u that,%v this,%t that,%x the other,%xx only once,%q the other,%z the other,%c cstuff

First field contents:this,
Entire match:%t this,%u that,%v this,

First field contents:that,
Entire match:%u that,%v this,%t that,

First field contents:the other,
Entire match:%x the other,%xx only once,%q the other,%z the other,
```